# How Twitter make Facebook's access tokens timeless?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-access-token

How Twitter make Facebook's access tokens timeless and they do not become obsolete.
Or Twitter and Facebook's access tokens is timeless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is (being deprecated - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) offline_access permission that application can request to have tokens without expiration, which is what is most likely used in this case (I have not verified it).